# AWS-Amplify globally sign out all users on "forgot password"

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have a use case where I would like to globally sign-out a user from all devices/clients if a user changes their password through the "forgot password" flow. Presumably, this wouldn't be an issue if a user were to "change password", as I could assume a user is already authenticated and thus call `Auth.signOut({ global: true })`.

It doesn't appear that the [ForgotPassword][1] component from `aws-amplify-react` does this. Opening a browser and logging in, and opening another browser and confirming a new password doesn't invalidate the session in the first browser.

I've tried hooking into the Cognito UserConfirmation trigger and calling `adminUserGlobalSignOut` based on the trigger source.CloudWatch logs indicate that `adminUserGlobalSignOut` is resolving successfully, but there is no difference client-side. `Auth.currentSession()` and `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()` both return without errors.

Interestingly, I see that network calls to `https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/` are returning with a 400 status and `{"__type":"NotAuthorizedException","message":"Access Token has been revoked"}`, but I am unsure how I would hook into that.

I am wondering if anyone else has come across this issue, or have a work-around.

Comment: I couldn't figure it out, either, so I opened an issue on their Github: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/6559

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you are calling Auth.signOut({ global: true }) you are not signed in. After the forgotPasswordSubmit call, simply call signIn with the new password, and then signOut global.